# How to upload online generated audio to google app engine blob store

Tags: google-app-engine, audio

I am creating an application in java on google app engine in which a user can record his voice and upload to server.
I am implementing it in google app engine and have recorded audio and generate the url which have blob:http://xxx.xx  format. Now I want to upload it to blob store of google app engine.

How can I store this generated audio file . Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Google Cloud Storage, which will allow you to serve uploaded content directly (perhaps using your custom domain), without App Engine (like Amazon S3).

You can either use the `createUploadUrl()` method in `BlobstoreService`, which will allow the user to directly upload their file to the blobstore (after which a user-specified 'load handler' callback is executed), or the user can upload to your App Engine app and then use the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) to write the blob to GCS.

Using the Cloud Storage Client Library, you can specify the file 'path' (it's not really a path) and the access control rules.  These files can then be served as static content from GCS, if that's what you want.  If you want to control access to the uploaded files, your App Engine app can use the same client library to read from GCS and serve it back to the user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague but I'll try to answer it. There are a number of concepts and technologies involved.
This can be the jsp file (the form is created with jQuery UI):

```
<div id="audio-upload-form">
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadAudio") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="fileblob" id="fileblob" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" required />
    </fieldset>
    <button class="upload-video" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And this can be the back end controller (implemented with Java and Spring MVC):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAudio", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadAudioServlet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, JSONException {

        Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
        BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("fileblob");
    }
```

Now the blob is uploaded and the blobKey is generated. You can use this key to create a URL that you can use to access the audio file. I'm imagining something like a list of clickable audio files which start playing in the browser itself when you click on them. Will be happy to help once you provide more details.